# Ошибка компиляции ядра от micode

Tags: android, компиляция, kali-linux

Хочу собрать ядро nethunter под свой телефон использую инструкцию undermind'а ,но пустя пару ошибок вылетает это

```
  MODPOST vmlinux.o
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  UPD     include/generated/compile.h
  CC      init/version.o
  LD      init/built-in.o
drivers/built-in.o: In function `mdss_dsi_find_panel_of_node':
/home/user123/Загрузки/mykernel/drivers/video/fbdev/msm/mdss_dsi.c:3043: undefined reference to `hq_regiser_hw_info'
/home/user123/Загрузки/mykernel/drivers/video/fbdev/msm/mdss_dsi.c:3025: undefined reference to `hq_regiser_hw_info'
/home/user123/Загрузки/mykernel/drivers/video/fbdev/msm/mdss_dsi.c:3034: undefined reference to `hq_regiser_hw_info'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `mdss_fb_change_hbm':
/home/user123/Загрузки/mykernel/drivers/video/fbdev/msm/mdss_fb.c:1155: undefined reference to `ktd_hbm_set'
/home/user123/Загрузки/mykernel/drivers/video/fbdev/msm/mdss_fb.c:1153: undefined reference to `ti_hbm_set'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `gtp_hw_info':
/home/user123/Загрузки/mykernel/drivers/input/touchscreen/gt1511q/gt1x.c:753: undefined reference to `hq_regiser_hw_info'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `msm_sensor_driver_probe':
/home/user123/Загрузки/mykernel/drivers/media/platform/msm/camera_v2/sensor/msm_sensor_driver.c:1226: undefined reference to `hq_regiser_hw_info'
/home/user123/Загрузки/mykernel/drivers/media/platform/msm/camera_v2/sensor/msm_sensor_driver.c:1195: undefined reference to `hq_regiser_hw_info'
/home/user123/Загрузки/mykernel/drivers/media/platform/msm/camera_v2/sensor/msm_sensor_driver.c:1211: undefined reference to `hq_regiser_hw_info'
/home/user123/Загрузки/mykernel/drivers/media/platform/msm/camera_v2/sensor/msm_sensor_driver.c:1222: undefined reference to `hq_regiser_hw_info'
drivers/built-in.o:/home/user123/Загрузки/mykernel/drivers/media/platform/msm/camera_v2/sensor/msm_sensor_driver.c:1199: more undefined references to `hq_regiser_hw_info' follow
make: *** [Makefile:1100: vmlinux] Ошибка 1
root@user123:/home/user123/Загрузки/mykernel#
```

Пробовал копаться в макефайле ,так ничего и не нашел. Если что исходники брал эти https://github.com/MiCode/Xiaomi_Kernel_OpenSource/tree/pine-p-oss

Comment: Посмотрите на права и владельца файлов. Возможно все это надо собирать от рута (через sudo)

Comment: Я собираю от имени администратора (root)ну или по вашему sudo

Comment: для начала уберите кириллицу из путей сборки. хоть на дворе 21век, всеж иногда пробелы и не ascii бывают ломают сборку. может баг. а вообще undefined reference to `hq_regiser_hw_info' говорит о том, что либо не скомпилировался ранее какой-то файл. либо забыли включить нужный .о в линковку, и он данную функцию найти не может. поищите в исходниках где она определена, возможно в Makefile где-то ошибка, ну либо вы неправильно выполнили конфигурационный скрипт.

Comment: В makefile ничего интересного не нашел. Может кто знает какая переменная в конфиг файле отвечает за 'hq_regiser_hw_info' ?

Answer (score 0):

Надо было в конфиг файле кое что подкорректировать например в ошибке 'hq_regiser_hw_info' надо было включить CONFIG_HQ_SYSFS